# Alarm being called twice in android

Tags: android, file-io, alarm, android-alarms, voice-recording

I am trying my project on Voice Reminder.It is based on voice recording and set it to alarm.My problem comes when alarm gets activated.It gets activated twice.
Here is my code.So please if anybody can help it.

```
AudioAppActivity (MainActivity file)

public class AudioAppActivity extends Activity {

private static MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
private static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

private Button recordButton;
private Button playButton;
private Button stopButton;
private Button database;
private String audioFilePath;
private static int c = 0;

private boolean isRecording = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_audio_app);

    // INITIALISATION

    recordButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    playButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    database = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

    // FETCHING OF STATIC VALUE OF COUNTER

    SharedPreferences spf = getSharedPreferences("COUNTER_VALUE",
            MODE_PRIVATE);
    c = spf.getInt("counter", 0);

    // CHECKING OF MICROPHONE

    if (!hasMicrophone()) {
        stopButton.setEnabled(false);
        playButton.setEnabled(false);
        recordButton.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        playButton.setEnabled(false);
        stopButton.setEnabled(false);
        recordButton.setEnabled(true);
    }

    // ON CLICK OF RECORD BUTTON

    recordButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // CREATING DIRECTORY FOR RECORDINGS

            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getAbsolutePath() + "/Mydir");

            if (!f.exists()) {

                f.mkdir();
            }

            audioFilePath = f.getAbsolutePath() + "/myaudio" + c + ".3gp";
            c = c + 1;

            isRecording = true;

            playButton.setEnabled(false);
            recordButton.setEnabled(false);
            stopButton.setEnabled(true);

            try {

                mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                mediaRecorder
                        .setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(audioFilePath);
                mediaRecorder
                        .setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                mediaRecorder.prepare();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mediaRecorder.start();

        }

    });

    // ON CLICK OF STOP BUTTON

    stopButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            stopButton.setEnabled(false);
            playButton.setEnabled(true);

            if (isRecording) {
                recordButton.setEnabled(true);
                mediaRecorder.stop();
                mediaRecorder.release();
                mediaRecorder = null;
                isRecording = false;
            } else {
                mediaPlayer.release();
                mediaPlayer = null;
                recordButton.setEnabled(true);
            }

        }
    });

    // ON CLICK OF PLAY BUTTON

    playButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            playButton.setEnabled(false);
            recordButton.setEnabled(false);
            stopButton.setEnabled(true);

            try {

                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(audioFilePath);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

    database.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent i = new Intent(AudioAppActivity.this,
                    DatabaseActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

protected boolean hasMicrophone() {
    PackageManager pmanager = this.getPackageManager();
    return pmanager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_MICROPHONE);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences("COUNTER_VALUE",
            MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = sp.edit();
    spEditor.putInt("counter", c);
    spEditor.commit();

    super.onDestroy();

}
```

DatabaseActivity.java

```
    public class DatabaseActivity extends Activity {

private static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
ListView lv;
int i = 0, pos;
String fileName;
List<String> filenames = new ArrayList<String>();
TimePicker tp;
TimePickerDialog tpd;
final static int RQS_1 = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_database);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    File f2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath() + "/Mydir");

    if (!f2.exists()) {

        f2.mkdir();
    }

    File[] files = f2.listFiles();

    if (files.length > 0) {
        for (File ff : files) {
            filenames.add(ff.getName().toString());
        }

        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(DatabaseActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, filenames));
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(DatabaseActivity.this,
                "There are no files...(onCreate)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                int position, long arg3) {
            pos = position;
            fileName = lv.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getAbsolutePath() + "/Mydir");

            try {
                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(f.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();
                Toast.makeText(DatabaseActivity.this, "PLAYING...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

    lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            fileName = lv.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
            registerForContextMenu(lv);
            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    if (v.getId() == R.id.listView1) {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("File Options");
        menu.add(0, 1, 0, "SCHEDULE");
        menu.add(0, 2, 0, "DELETE");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    String v = lv.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath() + "/Mydir");
    if (id == 1) {
        openTimePickerDailog();
    }

    else if (id == 2) {
        File file = new File(f.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + v);
        boolean deleted = file.delete();

        if (deleted == true) {
            Toast.makeText(DatabaseActivity.this, "FILE DELETED!!!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Refresh();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(DatabaseActivity.this, "FILE NOT DELETED!!!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public void openTimePickerDailog() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    tpd = new TimePickerDialog(DatabaseActivity.this, settime,
            cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false);
    tpd.setTitle("Set Alarm Time");
    tpd.show();
}

OnTimeSetListener settime = new OnTimeSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();
        calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        if (calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0) {
            // Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
            calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
        setAlarm(calSet);
    }
};

protected void setAlarm(Calendar calSet) {
    Toast.makeText(
            DatabaseActivity.this,
            "Alarm Received for file:' " + fileName + "' at time "
                    + calSet.getTime(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("key", fileName);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet.getTimeInMillis(),
            pendingIntent);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}

protected void Refresh() {
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    lv.setAdapter(null);

    File f2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath() + "/Mydir");

    if (!f2.exists()) {

        f2.mkdir();
    }

    File[] files = f2.listFiles();

    if (files.length > 0) {
        for (File ff : files) {
            filenames.add(ff.getName().toString());
        }

        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(DatabaseActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, filenames));
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(DatabaseActivity.this,
                "There are no files...(onResume)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

    }

    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.database, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Alarm Reciever

```
    public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private String filename;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    filename = intent.getExtras().getString("key");

    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath() + "/Mydir");

    try {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(f.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + filename);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
        Toast.makeText(context, "PLAYING...",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using  PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT while creating pending intent

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and it kind of weird but i solved it by moving my alarmmanager initializer from inside onCreate method to onStart method, also i removed the line of code setting my view orientation dynamically and now setting it from my manifest.xml